# AWS ECS Service Discovery Cors Issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I am implementing a full stack app on ECS with Service Discovery Enabled. The infrastructure consists of a backend which talks to a mysql RDS database and a frontend with VueJS which makes request to the nodejs backend. I am running into a CORS issue when I make a request from the frontend. To reproduce the issue:

1. Clone https://github.com/FIAF0624/backend-infra
2. terraform init
3. terraform plan
4. terraform apply
5. When the mysql instance is up and running, connect to the database using `mysql -h <endpoint> -u admin -padmin123` and run the following query :

   ```
   DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS customer;

   CREATE DATABASE customer;
   USE customer;
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;


   CREATE TABLE books (
     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     price int NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );

   INSERT INTO books VALUES (1,'Basic Economics', 20),(2,'Harry Potter', 15),(3,'Physics', 17);
   Select * from books
   ```
6. Clone https://github.com/FIAF0624/frontend-infra
7. terraform init
8. terraform plan
9. terraform apply
10. Go to ECS -> rolling-ls-cluster -> Tasks -> Enter the Public IP in browser and click on the button.
11. Check the browser console ( Right click -> Inspect -> Console ) and you will see the following error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.example.terraform.com:3300/mysql' from origin 'http://<public-IP>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

GET api.example.terraform.com:3300/mysql net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) rt {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

However if I create an EC2 instance and make a request using
`curl api.example.terraform.com:3300/mysql`, I get the response back.

This is my NodeJS backend: https://github.com/FIAF0624/backend/blob/main/server.js and I have allowed CORS as well explicitly adding the headers. The Security group allows all traffic from anywhere. Not sure why I am running into this CORS issue. The app runs locally for me just fine. I am not sure where the issue exactly is.

This is the frontend repo: https://github.com/FIAF0624/frontend/blob/a2e89010d3dfaa75caecfb8d656723abe2ff3456/src/components/Dashboard.vue#L29 where I am using Axios to make a request.

Comment: `api.example.terraform.com:3300/mysql` is missing a scheme/protocol.

Comment: @jub0bs Thank you for looking into it. Can you please specify where would i set that?

Comment: No idea, but that what that error message is telling you.

Comment: *Can you please specify where would i set that?* - wherever [`$BASE_URL_VALUE`](https://github.com/FIAF0624/frontend/blob/a2e89010d3dfaa75caecfb8d656723abe2ff3456/src/config.json) comes from?

Comment: @tevemadar Sure. It is actually being set in ECS task definition https://github.com/FIAF0624/frontend-infra/blob/88de17538cbaa36465935123158412532c72af6f/modules/ECS/definition.json#L7

Comment: I think you could simply put `https://` in front of it (or `http://` if it fails), and try what happens. It's not like you could connect to a single specific port with multiple protocols.

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you for looking into it. Will http or https be the right protocol? Because my backend is being exposed on port 3300.

Comment: @tevemadar `http://api.example.terraform.com:3300/mysql net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` doesn't seem to be working. :(. Same when using https.

Comment: and the default protocol is tcp and that is already setup by default.

Comment: The back end should use its own public dns name instead of `api.example.terraform.com`. The frontend can reference that as the BASE_URL. or use the public IP from the backend app.

Comment: @Matt Using a public DNS defeats the purpose of using service discovery. Service discovery enables containers to talk internally without leaving the network but introducing public dns means traffic is now going over the internet.

Comment: How is the front end/browser going to communicate with the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Frontend is not responsible for making the request to the backend. It only serves the Javascript, HTML and CSS. What is making the request in this case is the browser. So your browser/laptop is not on the same network as where the backend resides. This is why you are able to still make the request from the EC2 server.

Solution : Setup a VPN server ( OpenVPN or AWS VPN ) to interact with your VPC network. And then make a request and it should work. or alternatively, follow Matt's solution if you are okay with having a public DNS. but remember not every API will be public facing.

or alternatively you can also re route the request via a proxy server which in your case can be the EC2 instance which already resides in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

**jub0bs** is correct.

Although one other thing to consider is to ensure that CORS has not been set somewhere in the ECS configuration on AWS as well.

Because if that happens your CORS settings will get appended to the CORS settings of ECS and cause problems with unresolved CORS.